# Why do I need to call my mock like a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I've read all I can find with regards to Python 3 and mocking. Unfortunately, I still can't figure out why I need to verify assertions on `mock()` instead of `mock` when all documentation I've read use the latter.

Here is what I test looks like -

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from unittest import TestCase, skip
from suds.client import Client, ServiceDefinition
from run import WebService
import unittest

@patch('run.Client')
def test(self, mock):
    service = WebService()
    weather_id = 1234
    weather = service.get_weather(weather_id)
    mock().service.GetWeather.assert_called_once_with(weather_id)
```

`run` in this case is where `WebService` resides and `Client` is the `suds` client.

Printing `mock.mock_calls` I see -

```
[
    call('SERVICE_WSDL', proxy={'https': 'PROXY', 'http': 'PROXY'}),
    call().factory.create('AuthHeader'),
    call().set_options(soapheaders=<MagicMock name='Client().factory.create()' id='37553264'>),
    call().service.GetWeather(1234, '', '')
]
```

Mind you, my test passes. I'm simply wondering what I'm missing so I can better understand mocking in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's rename the variable because it's actually a mocked instance of `run.Client`:

```
@patch('run.Client')
def test(self, mock_client):
    # ...
    mock_client().service.GetWeather.assert_called_once_with(weather_id)
```

You're creating an instance of `Client` within `run` and you're using that in your code. But you're not actually mocking that instance in this test, you're mocking the class (`run.Client` is being patched).

So we have a mocked class and we're calling that class to create an instance. That instance is what your code actually uses. This means what you really want is access to the return value of the constructor of the class:

```
mock_client.return_value.service.GetWeather.assert_called_once_with(weather_id)
```

This is the same as your code except without calling `mock_client()`. Your current test code does something similar: call the mocked class, see what instance you get back and perform assertions on that. Yet the `mock` library provides the `return_value` attribute to do that already.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.